# update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/io.elementary.terminal doesn't exist

Tags: pantheon-terminal

since yesterday, I have no pantheon-terminal any more (elementary OS  0.4.1 Loki). Trying to install it yields this error message:

```
LANG=C sudo apt install pantheon-terminal
...
pantheon-terminal is already the newest version (0.4.3+r1069+pkg51~daily~ubuntu16.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/io.elementary.terminal doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package pantheon-terminal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 pantheon-terminal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

or when trying to `--reinstall`:

```
LANG=C sudo apt install --reinstall pantheon-terminal
...
1 not fully installed or removed.
...
E: Internal Error, No file name for pantheon-terminal:amd64
```

`apt install -f` doesn't work either.

What's wrong here? Thanks for any suggestions...

Comment: I'm confused...if you have no terminal, how are you executing the above commands? Anyway, just to see if it works, try uninstalling using 'sudo apt remove' then fix possible broken packages using 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' then do an update and re-install. Let us know if this works.

Comment: pantheon-terminal is not the only terminal in the world ;-) I have several installed, gnome-terminal, urxvt, guake and a few others... , reinstalling and re-configuring did not help unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have copied my answer from [my answer to question 15323](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/15323/im-having-this-issue-with-pantheon-terminal/15418#15418). The package is corrupt in elementary's daily ppa for Loki.

The problem seems to be that the apt package doesn't have the file `/usr/bin/io.elementary.terminal`
in it anymore.

To check for yourself, install `aptitude`, and run this in another terminal program:

```
aptitude download pantheon-terminal
```

The file will be ~4kB. You can open it in archive manager to investigate further. Inside, in the data portion, there's only `/usr/share/doc/`and `/usr/share/man/`

This only seems to happen when on the daily elementary PPA, which I don't know how it would be configured that way in the first place.

As Ernesto points out in a comment to his question, to fix it you will need to change your package source by removing the daily ppa and adding the stable one.

**How to fix it:**

You will need access to a terminal. You can press Ctrl-Alt-F1 to access one at `tty1` (Alt-F7 to return to your desktop afterwards), or install another from App Centre.

First purge the pantheon-terminal files from your system:

```
sudo apt purge pantheon-terminal
```

Then remove the daily ppa like this:

```
sudo apt add-apt-repository --remove ppa:elementary-os/daily
```

Then add the stable repository to your sources:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
```

Now you can update and install the terminal again:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pantheon-terminal
```

Answer (score 0):

As a quick work around until the package is fixed you can disable the post installation script:

Edit

> /var/lib/dpkg/info/pantheon-terminal.postinst

Comment out the if block

```
#!/bin/sh -e
set -e
#if [ "$1" = "configure" ]; then
#       update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator \
        x-terminal-emulator /usr/bin/io.elementary.terminal 35
#fi
```

Install and change back.