# I'm having this issue with pantheon/terminal

Tags: pantheon-terminal

Need to get 0 B/4,464 B of archives.
After this operation, 16.4 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package pantheon-terminal.
(Reading database ... 344254 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../pantheon-terminal_0.4.3+r1069+pkg51~daily~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pantheon-terminal (0.4.3+r1069+pkg51~daily~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up pantheon-terminal (0.4.3+r1069+pkg51~daily~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/io.elementary.terminal doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package pantheon-terminal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 pantheon-terminal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Having the same, have purged with apt, purged with dpkg, reconfigured and cleaned. Can't install

Comment: I solved it, this is what I did: 1. Remove the daily repository "sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:elementary-os/daily". 2. "apt-get update", 3. Remove pantheon-terminal and reinstalled it with apt-get. 4. apt-get upgrade. 5. Verify if another daily package is installed on the system, lucky for me it was just pantheon-terminal.

Comment: I tried all that, I'll just have to live without.

Comment: Dave make and apt-get update and apt-get upgrade after remove the daily repository.

Comment: What I did in the end was removed the daily PPA (I forgot it was a daily) and I added the stable channel for xenial (I'm on 17.10) and it installed perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just trying to get to the bottom of this in case more people see this issue. This answer is a bit haphazard.

The problem seems to be that the apt package doesn't have the file `/usr/bin/io.elementary.terminal`
in it anymore.

To check for yourself, install `aptitude`, and run this in another terminal program:

```
aptitude download pantheon-terminal
```

The file will be ~4kB. You can open it in archive manager to investigate further. Inside, in the data portion, there's only `/usr/share/doc/`and `/usr/share/man/`

This only seems to happen when on the daily elementary PPA, which I don't know how it would be configured that way in the first place.

As you point out in a comment, to fix it you will need to change your package source by removing the daily ppa and adding the stable one.

**How to fix it:**

You will need access to a terminal. You can press Ctrl-Alt-F1 to access one at `tty1` (Alt-F7 to return to your desktop afterwards), or install another from App Centre.

First purge the pantheon-terminal files from your system:

```
sudo apt purge pantheon-terminal
```

Then remove the daily ppa like this:

```
sudo apt add-apt-repository --remove ppa:elementary-os/daily
```

Then add the stable repository to your sources:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
```

Now you can update and install the terminal again:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pantheon-terminal
```